# append html to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I wanted to create a todo list. So far I've created an input tag for the name of the task and a Button to add the task.
Somehow the javascript code doesnt seem to work.

Im rather new to this topic so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.
What do I need to change for this code to work?

This is the code I'm using right now:
html:

```
<div id="pomodoro"></div>
    <div id="addPomodoro">
        <input type="text" id="name">
        <button id="add">Add Pomodoro!</button>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(
function () {
    $('#add').click(function () {
        document.allert("Hello World");
        var name = $('#name').val();
        $('#pomodoro').append('<p class="task">' + name + '</p>');
    });
}
);
```

Comment: `document.allert` should be `alert`?

Comment: Also it appears your using jQuery, alert("Hello World!"); will do just fine.

Comment: And it looks like your parens at the end are wonky?

Comment: Yuppers, just a few typos: http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/Lf33u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.allert("Hello World");` is not a valid function.

Use `alert('Hello World');` instead (because you are using jQuery).

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#add').click(function () {
            alert('Hello World');
            var name = $('#name').val();
            $('#pomodoro').append('<p class="task">' + name + '</p>');
        });
    });
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3pqTb/1/